# Insert a picture into an InlineShape

Tags: vba, ms-word

I’m writing a Document in which I have to include many Pictures. In the ongoing process the Pictures get changed many times.

My idea was to include Rectangle Shapes as placeholders and give them a suitable name. I created a Macro that selects the Shape, deletes the old Picture and inserts the new one into the Shape.

```
Sub InsertImage(Shape As String, Picture As String, Hight As Integer)
    Dim shp As Word.Shape
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim strExt As String

    strFile = "C:\Pictures"
    strExt = ".png"

    ActiveDocument.Shapes.Range(Array(Shape)).Select
    Selection.TypeBackspace
    Set shp = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddPicture(Anchor:=Selection.Range, FileName:= _
         strFile & "\" & Picture & strExt, LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True)
    With shp
        .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
        .Height = CentimetersToPoints(Hight)
    End With 
End Sub


Sub Insert1()
    InsertImage "Shape01", "Pic01", 10
End Sub
```

I want this for floating Shapes as well as for InlineShapes.

When I set my Placeholder Shapes to InlineShapes the TypeBackspace line deletes the InlineShape and the picture does not get inserted into the InlineShape.

Comment: Try using a one-cell table as the "container" for all the pictures and insert them all a InlineShapes. Where text wrap formatting is required, wrap the table instead of the image. That way the code can be the same for everything and the table cannot be deleted so easily.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. 
I considered this solution. But as far as i know, it is not posible to give a table an specific name.
But I wish to select the "container" easily by a significant name. 
Also, i want that the "containers"  to maintain their size.

Comment: A table (or a cell) can be bookmarked. The row height and column width can be set to an exact size.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for the help. After many struggles, the solution with Tables + Bookmarks works perfekt. 
Here is the code:

```
Sub InsertPic(Pic As String, Cut As Single)
Dim strFile As String
Dim strExt As String
Dim ils As InlineShape

strFile = "C:\Pictures“
strExt = ".png"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(Pic).Select
Selection.Delete

Set ils = Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture(FileName:= _
strFile & "/" & Pic & strExt, _
LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True)

    With ils
    .PictureFormat.CropBottom = CentimetersToPoints(Cut)
    .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
    .Height = .Range.Cells(1).Height
    If .Width > .Range.Cells(1).Width Then
       .Width = .Range.Cells(1).Width
    End If
    End With

ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add (Pic)

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub


Sub Insert01()
InsertPic "Image01", 20
MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

Some explanation:

For this code, the Bookmark and the Picture need the same Name. I made this to avoid mix-ups.

With the Selection.Delete command, the Bookmark gets also deleted, so I just added a new Bookmark with the same name at the end. I’m sure there are more elegant ways to solve this, but this solution works.

I have had many struggles because i wanted to crop the Picure. But the size gets changed to the size of the table-cell when its inserted and the cutting step comes afterwards. So the Picturs wasn´t filling the complete cell size. Therefore, I added a part to resize the Image to the table-cell Size. As well, im sure there are better ways to overcome this ...

Because of this resizing, the Makro needs a bit of time (at least for my document). So I disabled the Screenupdating.